# HTACCESS REDIRECT 301 with DELAY

Tags: php, .htaccess

In same directory of htaccess i was create a file called timer.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" 
            content="<?php echo $_GET['delay'];?>;URL=<?php echo
                     $_GET['target'];?>">
</head>
</html>
```

and in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ timer.php?delay=10?&target=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bvrzkes9pWk$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

and it no work. you can help me. thanks

Comment: Perhaps the incorrect `?&` url parameter concatenation and url= encoding. You should be more descriptive with your issue. "No work" doesn't suffice. What's the result of the redirect? What's the rendered HTML of your timer.php page? Error_reporting?

Comment: Gracias Mario, soy muy novato, y no entendi nada de lo que me dijiste, perdona.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a [sleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function:

```
<html>
<head>

   <?php 
   sleep($_GET['delay']);
   ?>
   <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" 
            content="<?php echo
                     $_GET['target'];?>">
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: gracias amigo, tampoco funciono.

Comment: @OmarPlazas Happy to help.  If this worked for you, don't forget to accept and upvote so that others might benefit.